# Finding a stationary point using Newtons Method for two variables.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, matlab, newton-raphson

So I've written a function in MATLAB which solves a non-linear system of equation:

$f(x,y) = 0$

$g(x,y) = 0$

for two variables.

I am now tasked with finding a stationary point (critical point) for a function f(x,y) using my newton method program.

How is this supposed to work? How is the newton method helpful with finding criticals points? I can't really see how to apply this.

I should also add, that for this specific problem I am given the function:

$f(x,y)= (x-1)^2 + (y-1)^2$

Since my function for the Newton method relies on two functions f & g as input arguments.

Should I then treat any function f as a two functions?

i.e:

$f(x,y)= (x-1)^2$ and $g(x,y)= (y-1)^2$?

Comment: The critical points of a function are the zeros of its gradient.

Comment: @avs The thing is that my newton function uses two functions as inputs. And finds a root. However I am only given a singel function, $(x-1)^2 + (y-1)$ for finding the critical point to. Should I treat this as two functions? I.e:

$f(x,y) = (x-1)^2 $and $g(x,y)= (y-1)$

Comment: No.  You want the gradient of $f$, which takes a 2-D vector and returns a 2-D vector:
$$
F(x, y) = \nabla f = \left(\partial_{x} f, \partial_{y} f\right) = \left( 2(x-1), 1 \right).
$$
Now, you want to look for the zeros of $F$ using Newton's method.  This requires computing the total derivative of $F$, which is a 2-by-2 matrix.

Comment: @avs I see. But how should I treat the second input function originally written for my function? Since they want me to use my function [x,y]=NewtonMeth(f,g,a,b) to calculate my critical point, so how should my function "g" be treated? Thank you for answering!

Comment: If you want the critical points of only $f$, and not of $g$, why would you feed $g$ into your function NewtonMeth ?

Comment: @avs My question exactly. I was first asked to write a matlab function which takes: 

[x,y]=NewtonMeth(f,g,a,b) 

and now I'm asked to use said Newton function to find a critical point for f(x,y). Oh well..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92286/discussion-between-avs-and-oxodo).